# Is it safe to use Email service that provided from webhosting for business use?

Tags: email, email-server

I work in a company who uses their web-hosting as their email provider, they use it for normal send, receive and basic contacts management, they use it in customers support, sales and marketing, I would prefer to use a dedicated or professional email hosting instead for this type of work.
So for business use is it safe to use the email hosting that is included with hosting package or go with a professional email provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd love to hear why you *can* trust them for webhosting but *not* for email, have you detected a specific problem? IMHO they're either professional and trustworthy enough to host everything or nothing at all; I can't imagine a scenario where I'd trust another business only a little bit and still be happy to give them any business. Or are they "trustworthy" but clueless on the email side of things (in which case maybe there's problems with the hosting that you don't know about)?

That's my answer I guess, they're either safe to use for everything or not safe at all.

Now a valid reason to move in my eyes would be features - there might be a reason to move to a more fully featured dedicated email provider if you will use the extra features they can give...

Comment: First their web access is bad and I have to find an open source client and install it secondly (mainly) I prefer to use providers such as yahoo, gmail because they have a good investment in email services, so going to someone who is specialized in this field would have a higher reliability in matter of implementing best practices. that is how I think about it, do I have a point or this is not valid point?

Comment: Well moving to someone else to get better features, legal compliance, etc. is certainly valid. It kinda sounded like you had trust issues with your provider, and I think if you have problem with that host then its best to move everything rather than just bits and pieces - if your online presence is important then that's an argument to move the email to a specialised email provider and the website to an equally specialised web host.

Comment: well after reading your comment, I should look for "better features, legal compliance" whether it is specialized email provider or not, and move the whole solution not the pieces was good point I didn't put in mind, thx

Answer (score 3):

That being said (Robert - good answer) there are juridsictions where you get into painful ltrouble when using the normal web hosting email or gmail.

Like germany. ;)

Using your webhost or a normal Linux local email service and we have a dispute over something? You violated company law.... because you ned to keep email archives for 10 years in a way that is not manipulatable by normal emmployees. Emails are business documents, like invoices, contracts. Failure to properly handle them is... a falure to run the business proper. In a simple dispute (for example about warranty) that can then turns nasty becasue the accusation that you (as a company) do not keep your books in order for examlple turns around the legal argument (you have to proove I am wrong - not me I am right, because obviously you are too sloppy to keep your paperwork).

This is a little known fact... and one reason Exchange for example  has arvhiving methods server side available.

This would not be specific to any hosting, thougg, it covers peretty much all of them.

Comment: That's a good point, I had not considered any legal implications of types of service, which is embarrassing for me when I run our contract with mimecast for precisely this purpose. The business needs to determine the legal requirements (and what is *desirable* to make their lives easier) in choosing their email hosting, quite aside from the trustworthiness of any one hosting service.

Comment: Excellent point, I didn't consider it while looking for the issue